# ISP conflict on Raspberry Pi/Arduino SPI communication

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, spi

I'm working on a communication between a Raspberry Pi 3+ and an Arduino Nano. The Raspberry uses ISP pins to program the Arduino. After, both should communicate in full-duplex via SPI protocol, using the WiringPi library under Qt environment. The problem is that SPI only returns 0 on both slave and master side.

Is it possible that the ISP programmer enter in conflict with the SPI protocol, even if not used at the same time?

Master code:

```cpp
GpioMachine::GpioMachine(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent){

  wiringPiSetupGpio();
  wiringPiSPISetup(0,1000000);

  pinMode(CE0_PIN,OUTPUT);
}

void GpioMachine::sendSPI(int channel, int cmd,int arg)
{// send 2 bytes to slave

  unsigned char buffer[2];

  buffer[0]=cmd;
  buffer[1]=arg;

  wiringPiSPIDataRW(channel,buffer,2);

  int val;
  val=QChar(buffer[0]).toLatin1();
  int val2;
  val2=QChar(buffer[1]).toLatin1();

  qDebug()<<"spi get:"<<val<<val2;
}
```

Slave code:

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include "pins_arduino.h"

// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
   byte c=SPDR;
   Serial.println(c);
   SPDR=5;// random testing value to send to master;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SS,INPUT);

 // turn on SPI in slave mode
 SPCR |= _BV(SPE);
 SPI.attachInterrupt();

}

void loop()
{
  delay(10);
}
```

Both codes gives only zeros. Any Idea?